# Ubuntu 18.04 server - how to change or adjust operating system logging for a certain systemd service?

Tags: systemd, pam, ubuntu-18.04

I've tried quite a bit of Googling on this but have not come up with much so I figured I'd ask here.  Here's my current problem:

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 server pretty much stock.  The purpose of the server is to run a vision app.  The problem I'm having is when I check the journalctl for the vision app service, PAM (Pluggable Authentication Module) and some other operating system related services are logging excessively to the vision app, which I would rather they not do.  Here is an example:

```
journalctl -u visionapp.service | less
```

output:

```
(some stuff omitted)
Jan 08 10:43:12 visionapp sudo[2483]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/opt ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/iptables -F
Jan 08 10:43:12 visionapp sudo[2483]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan 08 10:43:12 visionapp sudo[2483]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jan 08 10:43:12 visionapp sudo[2490]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/opt ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/sysctl net.ipv4.conf.xxx999.forwarding=1
Jan 08 10:43:12 visionapp sudo[2490]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan 08 10:43:12 visionapp VisionApp[2471]: net.ipv4.conf.xxx999.forwarding = 1
Jan 08 10:43:12 visionapp sudo[2490]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jan 08 10:43:12 visionapp sudo[2493]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/opt ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/sysctl net.ipv4.conf.yyy888.forwarding=1
Jan 08 10:43:12 visionapp sudo[2493]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan 08 10:43:13 visionapp VisionApp[2471]: net.ipv4.conf.yyy888.forwarding = 1
Jan 08 10:43:13 visionapp sudo[2493]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jan 08 10:43:13 visionapp VisionApp[2471]: route: sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 88.88.88.63 --dport 77777 -j DNAT --to-destination 99.99.99.35:77777
Jan 08 10:43:13 visionapp sudo[2496]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/opt ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 88.88.88.63 --dport 77777 -j DNAT --to-destination 99.99.99.35:77777
Jan 08 10:43:13 visionapp sudo[2496]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan 08 10:43:13 visionapp sudo[2496]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jan 08 10:43:13 visionapp VisionApp[2471]: route: sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 88.88.88.63 --dport 5555 -j DNAT --to-destination 99.99.99.11:80
Jan 08 10:43:13 visionapp sudo[2499]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/opt ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 88.88.88.63 --dport 5555 -j DNAT --to-destination 99.99.99.11:80
Jan 08 10:43:13 visionapp sudo[2499]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan 08 10:43:13 visionapp sudo[2499]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jan 08 10:43:13 visionapp VisionApp[2471]: route: sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 88.88.88.63 --dport 6666 -j DNAT --to-destination 99.99.99.30:80
Jan 08 10:43:13 visionapp sudo[2502]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/opt ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 88.88.88.63 --dport 6666 -j DNAT --to-destination 99.99.99.30:80
Jan 08 10:43:13 visionapp sudo[2502]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan 08 10:43:13 visionapp sudo[2502]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jan 08 10:43:13 visionapp VisionApp[2471]: route: sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -d 88.88.88.63 --dport 23456 -j DNAT --to-destination 99.99.99.30:23456
Jan 08 10:43:13 visionapp sudo[2505]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/opt ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -d 88.88.88.63 --dport 23456 -j DNAT --to-destination 99.99.99.30:23456
Jan 08 10:43:13 visionapp sudo[2505]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan 08 10:43:13 visionapp sudo[2505]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jan 08 10:43:13 visionapp VisionApp[2471]: route: sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 88.88.88.63 --dport 28208 -j DNAT --to-destination 99.99.99.30:28208
Jan 08 10:43:13 visionapp sudo[2508]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/opt ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 88.88.88.63 --dport 28208 -j DNAT --to-destination 99.99.99.30:28208
Jan 08 10:43:13 visionapp sudo[2508]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan 08 10:43:13 visionapp sudo[2508]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jan 08 10:43:13 visionapp VisionApp[2471]: route: sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 88.88.88.63 --dport 2112 -j DNAT --to-destination 99.99.99.36:2112
Jan 08 10:43:13 visionapp sudo[2511]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/opt ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 88.88.88.63 --dport 2112 -j DNAT --to-destination 99.99.99.36:2112
Jan 08 10:43:13 visionapp sudo[2511]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan 08 10:43:13 visionapp sudo[2511]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jan 08 10:43:13 visionapp VisionApp[2471]: Make Routable: sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
Jan 08 10:43:13 visionapp sudo[2514]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/opt ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
Jan 08 10:43:13 visionapp sudo[2514]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan 08 10:43:13 visionapp sudo[2514]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
(some stuff omitted)
```

I changed some of the names and numbers to protect company anonymity but otherwise this is actual output.  I'd prefer to be able to suppress this in some way.

After consulting this post https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/327301/how-to-stop-sudo-pam-messages-in-auth-log-for-a-specific-user-on-ubuntu-16-04 I'd prefer to stay away from the PAM config files for 3 reasons:

1) I tried what the post suggested and it didn't work, and caused the vision app to crash.

2) Making a mistake editing the PAM logs could cause a lockout of root access

3) Some of the above messages do not seem to be generated by PAM

The last answer in the above post mentions filtering at the syslog level.  I've tried to read up on this but haven't been able to work out much so far.  I've at least been able to determine that the critical files seem to be `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and the files in 
`/etc/rsyslog.d/`.

here is my `/etc/rsyslog.conf/`:

```
$ cat /etc/rsyslog.conf

#  /etc/rsyslog.conf    Configuration file for rsyslog.
#
#           For more information see
#           /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-doc/html/rsyslog_conf.html
#
#  Default logging rules can be found in /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf


#################
#### MODULES ####
#################

module(load="imuxsock") # provides support for local system logging
#module(load="immark")  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# provides UDP syslog reception
#module(load="imudp")
#input(type="imudp" port="514")

# provides TCP syslog reception
#module(load="imtcp")
#input(type="imtcp" port="514")

# provides kernel logging support and enable non-kernel klog messages
module(load="imklog" permitnonkernelfacility="on")

###########################
#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####
###########################

#
# Use traditional timestamp format.
# To enable high precision timestamps, comment out the following line.
#
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# Filter duplicated messages
$RepeatedMsgReduction on

#
# Set the default permissions for all log files.
#
$FileOwner syslog
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022
$PrivDropToUser syslog
$PrivDropToGroup syslog

#
# Where to place spool and state files
#
$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog

#
# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
#
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
```

There are 3 files in `rsyslog.d`:

```
$ cd /etc/rsyslog.d

$ ls -l

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  314 Aug 15  2017 20-ufw.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  255 Apr 27  2018 21-cloudinit.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1124 Jan 30  2018 50-default.conf
```

I'm under the impression that `20-ufw.conf` and `21-cloudinit.conf` are for some other specific purposes.  Here is `50-default.conf`:

```
$ cat 50-default.conf

#  Default rules for rsyslog.
#
#           For more information see rsyslog.conf(5) and /etc/rsyslog.conf

#
# First some standard log files.  Log by facility.
#
auth,authpriv.*         /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none      -/var/log/syslog
#cron.*             /var/log/cron.log
#daemon.*           -/var/log/daemon.log
kern.*              -/var/log/kern.log
#lpr.*              -/var/log/lpr.log
mail.*              -/var/log/mail.log
#user.*             -/var/log/user.log

#
# Logging for the mail system.  Split it up so that
# it is easy to write scripts to parse these files.
#
#mail.info          -/var/log/mail.info
#mail.warn          -/var/log/mail.warn
mail.err            /var/log/mail.err

#
# Some "catch-all" log files.
#
#*.=debug;\
#   auth,authpriv.none;\
#   news.none;mail.none -/var/log/debug
#*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
#   auth,authpriv.none;\
#   cron,daemon.none;\
#   mail,news.none      -/var/log/messages

#
# Emergencies are sent to everybody logged in.
#
*.emerg             :omusrmsg:*

#
# I like to have messages displayed on the console, but only on a virtual
# console I usually leave idle.
#
#daemon,mail.*;\
#   news.=crit;news.=err;news.=notice;\
#   *.=debug;*.=info;\
#   *.=notice;*.=warn   /dev/tty8
```

To my knowledge these files are stock for an Ubuntu 18.04 server install.

So here are my questions at this point:

1) Should I edit one of the above files, or create another file in `/etc/rsyslog.d`, ex. `20-visionapp.conf` or similar?

2) Is there a way to change the above files to conditionally not include log messages for `visionapp.service`?  i.e. if a log line contains `pam_unix(sudo:session)` or `root : TTY=unknown` to not include it?  If somebody can suggest such a line, please clarify if it would apply to all `systemd` services or only to `visionapp.service` specifically, and also if it would apply to all users or for a specific user?  If options are available where both of these could be chosen that would be even better.

-- Update --

After more Googling, I did the following:

```
cd /etc/rsyslog.d
sudo nano 20-visionapp.conf
```

in `nano` I entered:

```
:msg,contains,"pam_unix" /var/log/PAM.log
& stop
```

then from the command line again I did:

```
service rsyslog restart
```

Then started and stopped the vision app again.  I was hoping that any message containing `pam_unix` would now go to the file `/var/log/PAM.log`, but when I ran `journalctl -u visionapp.service | less` the `pam_unix` messages were still there.

I think I'm at least getting close here.  What am I doing wrong?  Any suggestions?

-- Update2 --

Based on this documentation https://www.rsyslog.com/discarding-unwanted-messages/ for `/etc/rsyslog.d/20-visionapp.conf`, I also tried:

```
:msg,contains,"pam_unix" ~
```

and

```
:msg, contains, "pam_unix" ~
```

Neither of these work, i.e. `journalctl -u visionapp.service | less` still shows the `pam_unix` messages.

I should also mention that this post https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/133898/why-does-rsyslogd-not-honor-the-following-lines-in-rsyslog-d describes a very similar problem and does not yet have an accepted answer.

-- Update3 --

If I do this:

```
sudo nano /etc/rsyslog.d/19-visionapp.conf
```

then enter:

```
:msg, contains, "pam_unix" /var/log/visionapp-other.log
& stop
```

Then all the messages with `pam_unix` log to both `/var/log/visionapp-other.log` and to `journalctl -u visionapp.service | less`.  It seems from this post https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8737/rsyslog-is-not-discarding-message-as-it-should this has been a known bug in the past.  Does anybody have a workaround or any more information on this?

-- Update4 --

After more Googling I'm convinced that the steps I mentioned in the previous update are correct and there is either a bug in `rsyslog` or the integration of `rsyslog` into Ubuntu 18.04 server.  The workaround I've settled on for the moment is to make a script in the home directory containing:

```
journalctl -u visionapp.service | grep -v "pam_unix" | grep -v "TTY=unknown" | less
```

This screens out the messages with `pam_unix` and `TTY=unknown` that I'd rather not see.  This is clearly not a great solution and I'm disappointed in rsyslog and Ubuntu for not providing a better way to modify systemd log output.

Comment: Be careful with filtering out such log lines. They often contain important clues if your system is compromised.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'd at least like the option to filter these lines out.  I can always add a database setting in our product to change conf files to alternately include these files or not if the information proves essential at a later time.

Comment: The other issue is: Why does your product absolutely need to change firewall rules at runtime? Can this be done before the service starts instead? For instance, put the iptables setup in a script called by `ExecStartPre=`.

Comment: We don't need to change the firewall rules at runtime.  If the log info indicates that is occurring (honestly I'm not sure about that, I'm really a vision person and do server configuration only on occasion) then it's a general Ubuntu configuration that I'd rather not mess with and would prefer is not cluttering up my app's logs.

Comment: @cdahms As far as I know the fact that you manage to log to a specific file like in this example `:msg,contains,"pam_unix" /var/log/PAM.log`, it won't stop the `pam_unix xxx` messages from appearing, because you'd need to reject them. First you will need to find which facility the `appvision` APP belongs to and then create a special rule for that.

Comment: What is a "facility"?  I have a file /etc/systemd/system/visionapp.service that has the usual systemd content.  Is this what I need to modify, and if so, how?  How do I "reject" messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this by editing  `/etc/syslog.conf`

like this:

```
*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warning;\
    auth,authpriv.none;\
    cron,daemon.none;\
    mail,news.none      -/var/log/messages
```

you can change `=warning` to `=notice` `=info` etc according to the logging level you want